# Jumping a function inside the code with buffer over flow

Tags: buffer-overflow, c

My goal is the jump a local function without calling it. Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void bufferoverflow()
{
    printf("bufferoverlow!\n");
}

void doSomething()
{
    int buffer[10];
    // Only change here

    // Only change here end
    printf("doSomething!\n");
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    doSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

I have a address of bufferoverflow function. I found it with gdb. I added a breakpoint to bufferoverflow function and check the stack with bt command.

So how can ı execute the bufferoverflow function without calling it inside the doSomething method.

Comment: Is this a class assignment? If so, here's a great resource to help you get started: https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs161/fa08/papers/stack_smashing.pdf

Comment: You need to write some data to your buffer in order to overflow it, currently your code is not vulnerable to a buffer overflow.